# htaccess rewrite too many redirects codeigniter - non SSL to SSL except subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I should have a htaccess per site BUT I have one for 4 sites - 2 UK ones and 2 AU ones. It's one Codeigniter build. 2 sites are on dev.mydomain.extension for staging and 2 sites are live ones.

What I want to do:

1. Redirect anything `http://mydomain.co.uk` to
   `https://WWW.mydomain.co.uk`
2. Redirect anything
   `http://WWW.mydomain.co.uk` to `https://WWW.mydomain.co.uk`
3. Do NOT
   change `http://dev.mydomain.co.uk` at    all.

I'm trying the below but I always get the 'too many redirects' error and I don't think it will handle the www thing at all. I'm a bit out my depth.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
##setting 2 exceptions
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=dev.mydomain.co.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=dev.mydomain.com.au
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
##Codeigniter rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!dev\.)(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

##Codeigniter rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Remember to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Looking in incognito I get "redirected you too many times" with your code. I missed a rule out that is also included though:
`# Catch anything index.asp from the old site
RewriteRule ^(.*)\index.asp$ /$1 [R=301,L]`
In case it makes a difference. This is just before the codeigniter rules.

Comment: No I have already tested this rule on my Apache server and there is no redirect loop with this rule unless there is some other rule or code redirecting back to `http://`. btw incognito doesn't mean old cache is gone. Completely clear browser cache or test it using command line `curl`

Comment: I reduced it right down to first 6 lines (7 with the space) so no CI rules. Cleared cache, checked in proxy server, all too many redirects. It *does* say https: in URL bar though. So not sure if that means something - like it gets there and then there's a subsequent redirect.

Comment: Running your code elsewhere it worked. I narrowed it down to environment - rackspace/liquidweb cloudsites runs on load balancers and have more custom rules required. Ended up with the following (and repeated for .com.au). dev subdomain remained unaffected by these:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]`